# Pickadate - Start month with first day of the month and not first day of the week

Tags: javascript, pickadate

I am using [pickadate](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/) JS plugin to show calendar in an application. In there, the calendar shows a month starting with Sunday in the first column of the first row. But I want the calendar to start with first day of the month, irrespective of the day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like pickadate only allows Sunday or Monday as the first day. From the [docs](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/#first-weekday):

> The first day of the week can be set to either Sunday or Monday. Anything truth-y sets it as Monday and anything false-y as Sunday:
>
> > `$('.datepicker').pickadate({firstDay: 1})`